How to Implement Streaming in React Native?
I'm trying to implement streaming in a React Native application, but I'm encountering issues. Specifically, I'm using the react-native-fetch-api library along with react-native-polyfill-globals to make a streaming request, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
I've read this: Stream api with fetch in a react-native app
Could not get it working. After some debugging, I came up with this:
import 'react-native-polyfill-globals/auto';
import { fetch as fetchh } from 'react-native-fetch-api';

const streamBotResponse = async () => {
  const response = await fetchh(
    'URL...', 
    {
      headers: {
        ...
      },
      reactNative: { textStreaming: true },
    }
  );

  async function* streamAsyncIterator(stream: ReadableStream) {
    const reader = stream.getReader();
    try {
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        yield value;
      }
    } finally {
      reader.releaseLock();
    }
  }

  for await (const chunk of streamAsyncIterator(response.body)) {
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(chunk));
  }
};

Can't seem to resolve: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-fetch-api'.
Seems to me like this library does not support TypeScript (I could solve the error using a d.ts file but there is not a @types library for react-native-fetch-api (same goes for react-native-polyfill-globals))
But that is not a big problem, I managed to get it to sort of work, but my entire stream response is given back to me in 1 chunk. Is it possible to get it back in multiple smaller chunks? Or is this a limitation of RN and I should just give up on this?

Streaming in React Native can be challenging due to limitations in how streams are handled within the framework. However, one way to handle streaming is to use a WebView to leverage the browser's native streaming capabilities.
I managed to get it working like this:
...
import { WebView, WebViewMessageEvent } from 'react-native-webview';

const StreamComponent = () => {
  const webviewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');

  const getStreamData = () => {
    setMessage('');

    const injectScript = `
    (async()=>{
      const response = await fetch('YOUR_STREAM_URL/stream', {
          method: 'GET',
          responseType: 'stream',
          headers: {
            ...
          }
      });

      async function *streamAsyncIterable(stream) {
          const reader = stream.getReader();
          try {
              while (true) {
                  const {done, value} = await reader.read();
                  if (done) {
                      return;
                  }
                  yield value;
              }
          } finally {
              reader.releaseLock();
          }
      }

      for await(const chunk of streamAsyncIterable(response.body)) {
          const str = new TextDecoder().decode(chunk, {stream: true});
          window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(str);
      }
    })()
    `;
    webviewRef?.current?.injectJavaScript(injectScript);
  };

  const handleMessage = (event: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    const data = event.nativeEvent.data;
    setMessage((prev) => prev + data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ message });
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <>
      <WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        source={{ uri: 'YOUR_STREAM_URL' }}
        style={{ height: 80, width: '100%' }}
        onMessage={handleMessage}
      />

      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
        <Button title="Start Streaming" onPress={getStreamData}></Button>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default StreamComponent;



This link helped me a lot: https://dev.to/hieunh1801/react-native-chatgpt-stream-how-to-5cn
But this part:
const str = new TextDecoder().decode(chunk); - did not work for me
I had to do:
const str = new TextDecoder().decode(chunk, {stream: true});
Also, when you do: npm i react-native-webview, follow it up with a: npx expo install --fix (no need to eject as some other people have mentioned)
Make sure when you browse to YOUR_STREAM_URL specified in
source={{ uri: 'YOUR_STREAM_URL' }}
using your phone, you can see your API.
Note: Localhost will not work if your server is running on your PC and you are using your device (not an emulator) to test your app, therefore you need to use your network IP instead of localhost.
